# Cambiar el tamaño y estilo de la fuente de un label con F#

Tags: f#

Estoy haciendo pruebas con el lenguaje F# en modo Windows Forms, funciona todo bien pero no soy capaz de cambiar el tamaño y estilo de un label.

En el languaje `C#` es así a la hora de ejecutar el formulario.

```html
this.label_Mensaje.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Lo he intentado adaptar a F# de esta manera pero no funciona.

```html
label_Mensaje.Font <- Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)))
```

¿Alguna idea?

Saludos.

PD: Si quieren le doy el código completo del formulario. Lo que hace es abrir y cerrar la bandeja del lector. Solo que el label no lo puedo cambiar.

Código Visual F#:

```
open System
open System.Text
open System.Windows.Forms // Añadir refrencias.
open System.Drawing // Añadir referencias.
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

// Importar librería o dll externo.
[<DllImport("winmm.dll")>]
extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString,
        int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback)

let rt = StringBuilder(127)

// Método necesario para admitir el Diseñador. No se puede modificar
// el contenido de este método con el editor de código.
let form = new Form()
let label_Mensaje = new Label()
let groupBox_Bandeja = new GroupBox()
let button_Abrir = new Button();
let button_Cerrar = new Button();
groupBox_Bandeja.SuspendLayout()
form.SuspendLayout()

// groupBox_Bandeja
groupBox_Bandeja.Controls.Add(button_Abrir) // Añadir botones en el 
groupBox_Bandeja.Controls.Add(button_Cerrar) // groupBox_Bandeja.
groupBox_Bandeja.Location <- Point(22, 118)
groupBox_Bandeja.Name <- "groupBox_Bandeja"
groupBox_Bandeja.Size <- Size(227, 90)
groupBox_Bandeja.TabIndex <- 0
groupBox_Bandeja.TabStop <- false
groupBox_Bandeja.Text <- "Bandeja:"

// button_Abrir
button_Abrir.Location <- Point(26, 39)
button_Abrir.Name <- "button_Abrir"
button_Abrir.Size <- Size(75, 23)
button_Abrir.TabIndex <- 0
button_Abrir.Text <- "&Abrir"
button_Abrir.UseVisualStyleBackColor <- true

// button_Cerrar
button_Cerrar.Location <- Point(129, 39)
button_Cerrar.Name <- "button_Cerrar"
button_Cerrar.Size <- Size(75, 23)
button_Cerrar.TabIndex <- 1
button_Cerrar.Text <- "&Cerrar"
button_Cerrar.UseVisualStyleBackColor <- true

// label_Mensaje 
label_Mensaje.AutoSize <- true
//label_Mensaje.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)))
//member xyzzy.ChangeFontSize() = xyzzy.label_Mensaje.Font <- new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)
label_Mensaje.Font <- new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)
label_Mensaje.Location <- Point(12, 9)
label_Mensaje.Name <- "label_Mensaje"
label_Mensaje.Size <- Size(52, 55)
label_Mensaje.TabIndex <- 1
label_Mensaje.Text <- "?"
form.Controls.Add(label_Mensaje) // Añadir en el formulario.

// Crear formulario.
let AutoScaleDimensions = new Size(6, 13)
form.AutoScaleMode <- AutoScaleMode.Font
form.BackColor <- Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(114)))), ((int)(((byte)(54)))), ((int)(((byte)(161))))) // Color violeta.
let ClientSize = new Size(284, 261)
form.Controls.Add(groupBox_Bandeja) // Añadir en el formulario.
form.Name <- "Form1"
form.StartPosition <- FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
form.Text <- "Visual F# 2017"
groupBox_Bandeja.ResumeLayout(false)
form.ResumeLayout(false)
form.PerformLayout()
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Abrir la bandeja.
button_Abrir.Click.Add(fun _a ->
label_Mensaje.Text <- "Abriendo..."
Application.DoEvents()
mciSendString("set CDAudio door open", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero) |> ignore
label_Mensaje.Text <- "Abierto."
)


// Cerrar la bandeja.
button_Cerrar.Click.Add(fun _c ->
label_Mensaje.Text <- "Cerrando..."
Application.DoEvents()
mciSendString("set CDAudio door closed", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero) |> ignore
label_Mensaje.Text <- "Cerrado."
)

[<STAThread>]
Application.Run(form)
```

Comment: No se si te equivocaste al pasar el código pero te falt el "new" en el segundo código.

Comment: Si te refieres a esto, tampoco funciona. 
label_Mensaje.Font <- new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)

Ni con el =.
label_Mensaje.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)

Si que cuesta esto, me he pegado un tiemmpazo solo por esto y no conozco a nadie que lo logre.

Comment: Si puedes, copia todo el código donde inicializas el formulario antes de mostrarlo.

Comment: Ya me dirás cómo. No tengo idea. Te dejo el código completo aquí. Funciona, menos el tamaño del label.

No me cabe todo el código aquí. Si quieres te lo paso por correo.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta original

Comment: Editado, pero cuesta entenderlo. Si quires te lo paso por e-mail ;).

Comment: Aprobado. En la parte donde tienes que mirar es donde pone: // label_Mensaje

Answer (score 0):

No se si va a funcionar porque no tengo vs a la mano pero intenta lo siguiente:

```
 let emSize: float32 = 36.0f
 let label_Mensaje =
     let temp = new Label()
     do temp.AutoSize <- true
     do temp.Location <- Point(12, 9)
     do temp.Name <- "label_Mensaje"
     do temp.Size <- Size(52, 55)
     do temp.TabIndex <- 1
     do temp.Text <- "?"
     do temp.Font <- new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", emSize, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)
     temp

 form.Controls.Add(label_Mensaje)
```

Comment: Sigue danto problemas en el Font de las narices. DEjo una captura del error en este enlace. https://www.subeimagenes.com/img/captura-1882439.PNG

Comment: Creo que el problema está en el segundo parámetro del constructor de Font, pide un tipo float32 y el 36.0 lo detecta como float (sin 32). Supongo que un cast debería resolver el problema.

Comment: Modifiqué el código, a ver si así funciona.

Comment: Sigue con errores.
https://www.subeimagenes.com/img/captura-1883307.PNG

Comment: Mira que tengas bien el espaciado, recuerda que en f# al no haber ; ni {} el espaciado es importante (la sangría).

Comment: Verdad, un poco de sangrado fallaba, aún así, salió algo mal.
https://www.subeimagenes.com/img/captura2-1883823.PNG

Comment: A ver, prueba con el cambio que hice al código, en la primera línea.

Comment: Hola. Por fin funciona. Muchísimas gracias, es así: label_Mensaje.Font <- new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0uy)